# What exactly does $O(t^{1/3+\varepsilon})$ mean in this case?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Following is from http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa90/aa9023.pdf:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $\varepsilon > 0$. For all but $O(t^{1/3+\varepsilon})$ positive integers $n \leq t$, the derivative of the polynomial $f(x)=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n$ is irreducible.

I'm having trouble understand, what exactly is the $O(t^{1/3+\varepsilon})$ trying to say in this case?

When I look at big O notation definition (one of):

> $f=O(g)$ if and only if $\exists c, N>0$ such that $\forall x > N, f(x) < cg(x)$.

Say that we have $h(n)$ number of cases for which the polynomial in the clam is not irreducible, then the statement says that $h(n)=O(t^{1/3+\varepsilon})$ for some $t \geq n$ (or for all?), and so by definition of big O notation we have some $c,N$ such that $h(n)\leq c\cdot t^{1/3+\varepsilon}$ for $n>N$. Now it seems this is not correct interpretation (it does not seem to make sense), I guess what confuses me is the presence of $t$ , and then also the presence of $\varepsilon$. Could anybody explain the precise meaning of this?

Comment: I think epsilon goes to 0 as t grows.

Comment: Not $h(n)$, $n$ is a quantified variable $\forall n\leq t$ for the sake of the bound expressed by the $O$. Call $h(t)$ the number of $n$'s that are $\leq t$ for which $f'(x)=f_n'(x)$ is reducible. Then there is $C=C_\epsilon$, independent of $t$ but possibly dependent of $\epsilon$, such that $|h(t)|\leq Ct^{1/3+\epsilon}$. The $\epsilon$ and the $t$ are not dependent in this claim. The comment above is incorrect.

Comment: The statement is: Let $h(t)$ be the number of numbers $n\le t$ such that the derivative of  $1+\dots+x^n$ is not irreducible. Then $$h\in O(t^{\frac13+\varepsilon})$$ for every $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: Now it starts to make sense, will need to rethink this ... Thank you guys.

Comment: I think i get it, feel free to turn it into the answer if you like. But how can anyone be so fluent in big O notation, it is just so condensed...

Comment: @Sil Familiarity breeds fluency.  The more you see and use something, the more fluent you become.